# Uploading video on server through POST

Tags: android

I would like to know that how can I upload a video file on server using POST in  android. Please, let me know the answer, if anyone knows about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). It has sample code showing how to POST.