# Android - Post Video with additional data to the server

Tags: android, post

I would like to ask you how to upload video to the server with additional data (Multipart)
For example : 
The user should send his name, Email, Phone number and video from gallery.....
Thank you..

Comment: U better put some more information or code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
[Upload video from Android to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017093/upload-video-from-android-to-server)

http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://w3mentor.com/Upload.aspx");
byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
InputStreamBody isb = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(data),"uploadedFile");
        StringBody sb1 = new StringBody("someTextGoesHere");
        StringBody sb2 = new StringBody("someTextGoesHere too");
        MultipartEntity multipartContent = new MultipartEntity();
        multipartContent.addPart("uploadedFile", isb);
        multipartContent.addPart("one", sb1);
        multipartContent.addPart("two", sb2);
        postRequest.setEntity(multipartContent);
        HttpResponse res = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        res.getEntity().getContent().close();
```

Comment: Thanks , put how to send entered data from the user such as Name, Email and Phone while sending video.

Comment: in the above code the "one"/"two" are actually the name, email value...
i guess its clear now...