# Upload video to server in android

Tags: java, android, http, file-upload

I want to upload file to server in android   ,i am using the same code given  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5017146/1053800)
but when i run the code i get a :
`java.net.SocketException:Permission Denied`  exception at line:
`dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());`

`EDITED:`

one thing more that if a server requires authentication (means if the server requires some username and password to log in first and only then you can upload the files `example:Amazon s3`  ) then what changes i have to make in the same code.

what should i do.please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about the authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you added internet permission to you manifest file?

```
<manifest xlmns:android>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

I think the problem lies there

Comment: thanks ...i missed out that part ...

also please see the edited part

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your app manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the permission of INTERNET to make sure your application can upload your file to server.
add this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```