# Uploading video from phone

Tags: android, file-upload, upload, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have a website where the user of my application can upload a video from the Android Gallery. I want to make it so that when the user opens the file chooser it has an option to record a video and upload it from the Androids stock camera. Is this possible or would I have to create an application that would handle the video recording and post the video to the file chooser? Either way it would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to write your application, it will me be more customize and can be handles completely on your way . This link will help you related media recording [Media Recorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) and for uploading to server you can look in to this [Uploading video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017093/upload-video-from-android-to-server)