# FileNotFoundException when accessing file stored at /storage/emulated/0 directory in android

Tags: android, http-post, sd-card, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to pass the recorded video file saved in /storage/emulated/0/Videos/someVideo.3gp in android to remote server through POST HTTP method. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11151606/2082270) as a way to pass video file to remote server in FileBody format. But, at the end when I am trying to execute `httpClient.execute(request)` command it just keep throwing **FileNotFoundException**.

So, I don't understand why the video file is not accessible to outside world since I had saved it to sdcard using `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. I also had added write permissions to manifest file.

P.S. I am using Nexus 7 to test this. Please help..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you checking the existence of file before executing the `httpClient.execute(request)` ?

Referenced from the question that you are following:

```
File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
Log.e("Huzza", "Source File Does not exist");
return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
May be you are not converting the Path from Uri correctly on `onActivityResult(...) method`
I am sharing the code for getting correct path and it is working nicely in my Application.

```
String videoPath = "";
try 
{ 
 String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedVideoUri,
 filePathColumn, null, null, null);
 cursor.moveToFirst();
 int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
 videoPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
 cursor.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
 Log.e(TAG,
 "Error parsing Video path = " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: I added the check now..And, the file doesn't exists. However, I don't know the reason for the error. Since I am getting the filePath returned by the intent after video recording is done..

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issue in my implementation. Earlier I was actually trying to save the recorded video in custom folder in sdcard and hence it wasn't working. But when I tried your code and saved it to its default location it worked..! Thanks..