# Upload video by multi part request with header using REST API

Tags: android, multipart

I am uploading video,it is uploaded with out header request, i tried with request property,its not working.but i don't know how to
   add header with this code.
 I need to send video with api key in header.
i am asking api key in header request,not in  authorization.

```
public int uploadFile(final String sourceFileUri) {
                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                DataOutputStream dos = null;
                String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                String twoHyphens = "--";
                String boundary = "*****";
                String mm = "JJHJJHJHHKKJJKHHKHHKHKKKHHKHK";
                int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                byte[] buffer;
                int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
                File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
                if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    try {
                        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                        URL url = new URL("https:/fffs.co.in/ghh_site/api/video");
                        Log.d("WebService", "url=" + url);
                        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                     //  conn.setRequestProperty("X-API-KEY=","GHJJHGJGHGHJGHHJGJGHGGJ");
                     //  conn.getHeaderFieldDate("X-API-KEY", Long.parseLong(mm));
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                        conn.setRequestProperty("video_upload", filepathUrl1.getName());

                    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d("ssk", "result" + result);
                    return serverResponseCode;
                } // End else block
            }
```

The above code has no header,hw to add this in  multipart?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding header for HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732422/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection)

Comment: try this answer out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017093/upload-video-from-android-to-server

Comment: @Manojkumar i have to send api key in header request.how it can be done?

Comment: u want to send the x-api-key or authtoken

Comment: @Manojkumar x api key.

Comment: conn.setRequestProperty("x-api-key","key_value")

Comment: @Manojkumar iam sending,but i am getting empty response,this code work fine for you?

Comment: yes it does work

Comment: @Manojkumar in post man,api is working fine,but in my code ,i passed lik this."   conn.setRequestProperty ("X-API-KEY", "gokgo8gwskkog4ko4gco4okg4ws4o04k44w0go4k");"

Comment: try using lower case letters sometimes that creates a problem

Comment: @Manojkumar its not working.

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: from the above code you are returning serverResponseCode what is that, if you want to return the connection response code you have to use conn.getResponseCode()

Comment: int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    String line;
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                        result += line;
                    }

                }

Comment: check what response code you are getting. log it and see